# I cannot change permissions/users in developers console

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-console

When I'm trying to modify user permissions for my project in https://console.developers.google.com the page loads without success.

I can't change any users for my project. I've tried adding a new project and it's the same error. Do you overcome this error, or at least you had it?
[image]

There is a js error in the console
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem, but as a temporary workaround, you could use the command-line utility, gsutil: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

Comment: as I read in the documentation, you can't add/remove/change user permissions from gsutil.

Comment: Oh, permissions for the PROJECT. Sorry, I misread your question.